# Sfdx Auth Url is getting expired after certain time

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, salesforcedx-cli-auth

For CI pipeline for authentication I am using "sfdx force:Org:Display --targetusername ProductionHub --verbose" command to get **Sfdx Auth Url**. Then by using "sfdx **force:auth:Sfdxurl:Store** -f PseudFT_login.txt -d -a PseudFT " command getting logged in in the system.

But Sfdx Auth Url is getting expired after certain time. I want to know what is the lifetime of **Sfdx Auth Url** ? Also how can I extend it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sfdx Auth Url should never expire unless someone is revoking it manually or you have your own connected app and set the policies to say "`immediately expire refresh token` " or "`Expire refresh token if not used for n`" or "`Expire refresh token after n`"

By default the expiration of refresh token is set to "**Refresh token is valid until revoked**"

One way to find whats going on is look into your "**Connected Apps OAuth Usage** page by navigating to ***Apps >Connected Apps OAuth Usage*** in your org.

Comment: Not using connected app to get SFDX url,doing web login through SFDX CLI and running sfdx force:Org:Display --targetusername ProductionHub --verbose" to get SFDX URL: force://*.*.*@*salesforce.com ”Now storing this token in sfdxurl.txt and using in "sfdx force:auth:Sfdxurl:Store -f sfdxurl.txt -d -a PseudFT to authenticate into sandbox .Its working fine in CI pipeline but after some days it is getting expired and again need to capture  new sfdxurl token. How to find the exact issue or not even know the exact pattern when it is happening? Kindly let me know if you have any idea about this issue

Comment: Hi @Ananga Did you check Apps >Connected Apps OAuth Usage in your org to see if it says something about expiration or some one revoking it

Comment: I have check in the Oath usage, there is no such thing related to expiration. No one is revoking it also but still the token is getting expired. If this issue is related with session so can i extend the session to indefinite time.?

Comment: Cna you check your session ID time out in your org ?

Comment: its 2 hr but the token is getting expired some time after 1 day, sometimes after 304 hrs